# AuthKEY REST - Role service from REST endpoint

Tags: geoserver, geonode

I'm trying to setup Geonode and Geoserver advance security. I'm currently doing setup for the Geoserver.

I'm stuck at this step [Setup of the GeoNode REST Role Service](https://docs.geonode.org/en/master/advanced/components/index.html#setup-of-the-geonode-rest-role-service).
I cannot add new role service as i did not have `AuthKEY REST - Role service from REST endpoint` in the role service option.

[AuthKEY REST - Role service from REST endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK9I6.png).

currently using

1. **Django (1.6.11)**
2. **Geoserver 2.4.7**
3. **GeoNode (2.4.dev20170302183855, /vagrant/geonode)**
4. **django-oauth-toolkit (0.7.2)**

Answer (score 1):

AuthKey rest is supported in geoserver 2.9.3 and higher